# If $K$ is compact in $X$ then $K\cap S$ is compact in $S$ for any $S\subseteq X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let be $X$ a topological space. So I surely know that if $K$ is compact and closed then $K\cap Y$ is compact in $Y$ too for any closed $Y\subseteq X$. Now I am asking to me if $K$ and $Y$ are not closed then the statement holds again. Then **in particular** I ask if the statement if true when $X$ is the euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ equipped with the usual topopoly: indeed in this case if $K$ is compact then it is closed and bounded so that $K\cap Y$ is closed (in $Y$) and bounded too so that it is compact since the compactness is indipendent from the relative topology. Then if the statement is generally false in $\Bbb R^n$ too could it be true when $Y$ is a open space of a subspace $S$? So could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compact subspace $K$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ is *always* a closed subset. And if $Y$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, $K\cap Y$ doesn't have to be compact. For instance, $[0,2]$ is a compact subspace of $\Bbb R$ (with respect to the usual topology), but $[0,2]\cap(1,3)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. For example, let $D$ be the closed unit disk in the plane. It is compact. But $D \cap B(0,1/2)$ is not, where $B(0,1/2)$ is the open disk of radius $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general fact that if $K$ is compact and $Y$ is closed, then $K\cap Y$ is compact. In fact, consider $\mathcal U$ an open cover of $K\cap Y$. Then $\mathcal U\cup\{X\setminus Y\}$ is an open cover of $K$, from which a finite subcover $\{U_1,\cdots, U_m\}$ can be selected. If $U_i\ne X\setminus Y$ for all $i$, then this is already a finite subset of $\mathcal U$ which covers $K$, and a fortiori $K\cap Y$. If $X\setminus Y=U_i$, then $\{U_j\,:\, 1\le j\le m\land j\ne i\}\subseteq\mathcal U$ must cover $K\setminus (X\setminus Y)=(K\setminus X)\cup (K\cap Y)=K\cap Y$.

As for the rest, $(\text{compact})\cap(\text{non-closed})=\text{compact}$ is generally false, and in fact the better-behaved a space gets, the falser the statement is. For instance, in a Hausdorff space a subset of a compact subset is compact if and only if it is closed, if and only if it is closed in the subset topology. Therefore for Euclidean spaces you are asking for conditions to impose on a generic, non-closed subset $Y$ in order to achieve $K\cap Y$ closed. Which are... well, more or less $K\cap Y$ closed.

Comment: Okay, but if $S$ is compact in $X$ and $T$ is compact in $S$ with respect the relative topology induced by $X$ then $T$ is compact in $X$ even when $X$ is not hausdorff: is this incorrect?

Comment: Indeed the relative topology induced by $S$ (naturally this set is equipped with relative topology induced by $X$) is the same of that induced by $X$.